# Is there a way to install Python 3 modules into IDAPython with pip?

Tags: ida, idapython, python

I would like to use regular python packages in my IDAPython scripts, but I can't figure out how to install them into IDA's Python environment. I don't even know where this python environment is, or even where IDA's python.exe is, because `sys.executable` just prints the `ida.exe` file path. I can make it work with *some* packages, like yara and FIDL by installing them with pip, and copying the module's folder from my own python environment's `site-packages` folder over to `<IDA Install Path>\python\3\`, but this method doesn't work with more complex modules that have dependencies to other modules, or native DLLs (for example pywin32).

Is there an easier way to install python packages into IDA so i can just simply import them into my IDAPython scripts?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. Basically, IDAPython doesn't use my default system Python installation (in `C:\Python10`), instead it uses the one in `%localappdata%\Programs\Python\Python310\`. So all I had to do was to make sure that I'm calling `pip` in this python installation directory and not the default one, and now I can import pip packages into IDA.

Comment: _Actually_ IDAPython uses whatever you tell it to. Inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA` find (or create) an `REG_SZ` value named `Python3TargetDLL` and point it at whichever Python version you please, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Python310\python3.dll`. Normally you can use whichever `pythonXX.dll` you like, but I have issues with `python310.dll` vs. `python3.dll` in Wine. On Windows you can use `py` (Python launcher) to launch the default Python instance or select an alternative one. Don't recall where Python stores which is the default, but the installers offer the option.